# Tooltip is being cut off

Tags: html, css, angular

[image]

I am having troubles with my tooltip opening without being cut off. I am not sure what else to try to get this to open without being cut off.

```
 <th class="fd-table--header-cell" scope="col">
                    <p class="bold my-tooltip-header--cell" [innerHTML]="totals | fdContent"></p>
                    <a [attr.id]="totalsSelectory" [attr.aria-describedby]="totals"
                        href="javascript:void(0);" class="fd-tooltip-layer--selector">
                        <my-icon [myIconId]="totalsIconId" [content]="pageContent"
                            aria-label="icon" [title]="totals"></my-icon>
                    </a>
                    <my-tooltip [myId]="totals" [mySelector]="totals"
                    [content]="pageContent">
                        <div tooltip-content class="tooltip-margin">
                            <p aria-label="totals-tooltip--header"
                            [innerHTML]="totals| fdContent"></p>
                        </div>
                    </my-tooltip>
                </th>



    th {
        position: relative;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .my-tooltip-header--cell {
        display: inline;
    }
.fd-table--header-cell {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: em-calc(62px, 12px);
    padding: em-calc(12px, 12px);
}
```

Comment: What is it cut off by? The viewport? If so you might be better off detecting how much space you have to the viewport via JS and change the tooltip to popup under or on the side.

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip parent hold overflow hidden property, you need to remove it